# Jquery Style switcher - How to remove style flickering while a .css loads?

Tags: jquery, cookies, timeout, styles

I have a simple code to change styles with a simple clic. It works fine but it has a style flickering that i would like to prevent - a little timeout between one is disabled and other not totaly loaded -

Also i would like to add a cookie so user won't have to select their prefered style everytime he/she enters. But honestly i'm not sure how to do it as i'm new with jquery. So if someone is able to help me that will be great!

Thanks for reading!

I have this code to switch styles on my site:

HTML to call main style and main color

```
   <style type="text/css"> @import url("style.css");</style>
   <link href="yellow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Yellow Theme" />
```

Then i call the scripts as usual

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Each button has this:

```
    <a class="colorbox colorred" href="?theme=red" title="Red Theme"><img src="red.png" width="x" height="x" /></a>
```

Now here is the script.js code:

```
    google.load("jquery", "1.3.1");
    google.setOnLoadCallback(function()
    {

// Color changer
$(".colorblack").click(function(){
    $("link").attr("href", "black.css");
    return false;
});

$(".colorred").click(function(){
    $("link").attr("href", "red.css");
    return false;
});

$(".colorwhite").click(function(){
    $("link").attr("href", "white.css");
    return false;
});

$(".coloryellow").click(function(){
    $("link").attr("href", "yellow.css");
    return false;
});

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I've done a little more research and experimentation into this, and I think I've found a solution.  First some background info.  As far as I can tell, the problem we have with the flickering is the css not being fully loaded.  Generally you want the loading to be done at page load as long as it's not a major performance issue.  You could load them dynamically as needed but that leads to this problem we have here, where you are trying to use data that is not yet loaded.  The best solution that I can see is to load all of the css at the start and change their precedence dynamically.  I have tested this and it does work.  with cascading style sheets (css), the cascading part of the name means that when you load a style sheet and then load another one, the last one takes overriding precedence.  My first thought was to simply add another style sheet that would override the previous one.  That way, as it loaded, the old style sheet was still being used and there would be no flicker.  The only problem I ran into was that linked style sheet precedence is reversed, meaning you have to override the first one and not the last one.  Here is the code illustrating this process:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="yellow.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Yellow Theme" />
<link href="black.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Black Theme" />
<link href="white.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="White Theme" />
<link href="red.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" title="Red Theme" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".colorblack").click(function(){
    $("link:first").attr("href", "black.css");
    return false;
  });

  $(".colorred").click(function(){
    $("link:first").attr("href", "red.css");
    return false;
  });

  $(".colorwhite").click(function(){
    $("link:first").attr("href", "white.css");
    return false;
  });

  $(".coloryellow").click(function(){
    $("link:first").attr("href", "yellow.css");
    return false;
  });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <a class="colorbox colorred" href="?theme=red" title="Red Theme">red theme</a></br>
 <a class="colorbox colorblack" href="?theme=black" title="Black Theme">black theme</a></br>
 <a class="colorbox colorwhite" href="?theme=white" title="White Theme">white theme</a></br>
 <a class="colorbox coloryellow" href="?theme=yellow" title="Yellow Theme">yellow theme</a></br>
</body>
</html>
```

And the css is pretty simple. e.g.

```
body
{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

This works in Chrome and FF, but it does not work in IE or Opera.  Replacing link nodes seems to not work as well in those two.  But basically, that's how you do it. :)

Comment: Hi Joseph, Thanks again :)

Even if I found last night a different solution doing it with php (also i figured it out to add the cookies with php). I consider your idea it's great but i just tried it and is not working on IE.

Also, the new code works great with wordpress themes, but i'll keep yours in mind. 

Thank you so much, for your help, and i'll continue looking for a good way to add it with jquery and the help you gave me. :)

Comment: It seems I can't vote yet :( , but your help has been really useful to direct me! thanks

Comment: no problem :) Just glad you found a solution.  It was fun for me to just play around with it. XD

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try is having two link elements.  The default one placed first in the head and the user preference one second.  Since style sheets cascade, the first one will be overridden. Then you can replace the first one with that same style sheet so that the user can make another selection if he/she so desires.

Comment: Hi Joseph thanks for your answer, the main issue appears whith the background, as the bg color changes while it loads for example black.css the background goes white for some seconds. So i'm looking the way to maybe add a timeout after the clic while it loads the style so it won't get a white bg. But I have been trying with no luck. Thanks again!

Comment: I've never tried that before, but I'm hoping that what you can do is load a second one.  As the second one is loading, the first style rules (from yellow.css) are still in effect.  Once the second one is loaded, any style rules are replaced (background-color for instance).  Now you can replace the first one.  It won't change the actual look of the page, because the second style sheet has precedence.

I have to go offline for tonight, but if you are still having the issue tomorrow, I'll see if I can help.  Sounds like this could be pretty easy to fix one way or another. :)